# iPhone SDK: How to trigger drawRect on UIView subclass after orientation change?

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawrect

I am subclassing a UIView and overwrite the drawRect method. I'm noticing that the view's drawrect is only being called when the view first loads. After that it is never called again. How to I make sure it gets called after an orientation change? I've tried calling setNeedsDisplay on the view before and after the rotation and that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
[myView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
```

You can set this in IB as well (i.e., set mode to "redraw")

Comment: See the original author's response below. setNeedsDisplay is indeed the right method call.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay:` is used when you want to programmatically trigger a redraw. When you want orientation changes to trigger a redraw then `setContentMode:` is the ticket.

Answer (score 9):

This was a bug related to something completely different. setNeedsDisplay does indeed cause drawRect to be called.

Comment: Yes `setNeedsDisplay:` will trigger a redraw, but requires the programmer to explicitly invoke it. 'setContentMode:` will automagically trigger a redraw on an orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

to answer this and the other 94,000 similiar questions about view rotation/drawrect funkiness,

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self=[super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
        self.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    }
    return self;
}
```